# Ember subviews table doesn't work Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of null

Tags: ember.js, null, html-table, nextsibling

When I use table, subviews doesn't work.

For example this works fine

```
{{#each}}
    {{view App.RowView}}
{{/each}}
```

But this breaks

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    {{#each}}
        {{view App.RowView}}
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Error says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of null

**EDIT**: Here's the link to jsbin http://jsbin.com/nodotize/1/edit when you try to add item, it fails and throws error, but if you copy the text from rowView template and paste it between each it then works http://jsbin.com/nodotize/5/edit

Comment: do you mean RowView is not rendering??..but the the way i see it nextSibling error is not related to the RowView rendering...the error may just halting its rendering...i need more code to debug...

Comment: I added a link to jsbin.

Comment: i think its a metamorph issue...when you add views or oberservers, ember appends some `<script>` tags along..Ember is selecting <script> tag from table, and trying to do DOM ops which is not happening...you have your solution in 2nd link anyways...Ember people very soon are removing metamorphs anyways...

Comment: Thanks for the insight on what's happening. The thing is that I want to do custom JavaScript effects on row after it's added. Only way I know is via didInsertElement function, for which I need to create child view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `tagName: 'tr'` as a property on `rowView`, and removing the `<tr>`s from the template should solve the problem: http://jsbin.com/nodotize/6/edit

The default `tagName` for a view is `div`, but for table rows, this would result in invalid markup, so Ember must be detecting the context and adjusting this property for the generated view to `tr`.

If you manually define a view for a table row you’ll need to set the `tagName` to `'tr'`